# When using sys.stdout.write, "None" appears after what I write

Tags: python, python-2.7

My code looks like this:

```
import sys
print "What are his odds of hitting?", ( 25.0 / 10.0 ) * 8 + 65, sys.stdout.write('%')
```

When I run it in Powershell (Windows 7), I get this:

```
What are his odds of hitting? 85.0%None
```

What I want to get is this:

```
What are his odds of hitting? 85.0%
```

Why do I get the "None" at the end of it? How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing the *return value* of the `sys.stdout.write()` call:

```
print "What are his odds of hitting?", ( 25.0 / 10.0 ) * 8 + 65, sys.stdout.write('%')
```

That function returns `None`. The function **also** writes to the same file descriptor as `print` does, so you are *first* writing `%` to stdout, then ask `print` to write more text to `stdout` including the return value `None`.

You probably just wanted to add `%` at the end there without a space. Use string concatenation or formatting:

```
print "What are his odds of hitting?", str(( 25.0 / 10.0 ) * 8 + 65) + '%'
```

or

```
print "What are his odds of hitting? %.02f%%" % (( 25.0 / 10.0 ) * 8 + 65)
```

or

```
print "What are his odds of hitting? {:.02f}%".format((25.0 / 10.0 ) * 8 + 65)
```

The two string formatting variations format the floating point value with two decimals after the decimal point. See [String formatting operations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) (for the `'..' % ...` variant, old style string formatting), or [Format String Syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) (for the [`str.format()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), a newer addition to the language)

Answer (score 1):

`sys.stdout.write('%')` returns `None`. It simply prints the message and does not return anything.

Just put `"%"` at the end instead of calling `sys.stdout.write`

Or, you can use `.format()` here:

```
print "What are his odds of hitting? {}%".format(( 25.0 / 10.0 ) * 8 + 65)
```